# evaluate xml value as equation

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xproc

I'm trying to evaluate a equation inserted as value of xml tag using Xquery, Xpath or Xproc - in simple word in pure XML. I'm beginner here, but in my opinion it should be doable. To better demonstrate what I want to achieve, please see this example:

```
<inp> 
 <data>
   <a>5</a>
   <b>4</b>
 </data>
 <eq>
   a+b
 </eq>
</inp>
```

Now there will be some magic... and as result I'd like to get something like:

```
 <res>
  9
 </res>
```

Could you help me with the magic involved? At least point to correct tech - xquery, xpath or xproc to do it. Thanks.
Todor

EDIT: 
To avoid accusations that I didn't do any research - it's part of the question. I'm trying to determine the best technology from xml family to use. That's why I'm asking for direction to solution not for solutions :). Thanks. 
PS> of course, I'd be grateful for solutions, but I don't want to use more of your time than necessary .

Comment: Why should the result be `5`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake. It should have been 9.

Comment: Try giving XSLT a look. Not sure it's optimal, but I'm confident it can solve the problem.

Comment: What kind of formula syntax can be entered in the `eq` element?

Comment: Mathias: Simple math formulas with +,-,*,/ operators with brackets containing either numbers or variables that defined in data tag. Nothing more than that.

AndersNK: thanks. I'll explore that over weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the syntax to be XPath-compatible, so it's `$a+$b` rather than `a+b`, then it's easy to do using XSLT 3.0's xsl:evaluate or the eval() extensions offered in a processor-specific way by various XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 processors. The 3.0 solution would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="inp"
  <xsl:evaluate xpath="eq" 
       with-params="map:merge(
            for $p in data/* return map{node-name($p): data($p)})"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I would add that I implemented an application for a client that did this many years ago, and I've seen similar things many times. In their case they were using an XML document containing formulae which determined the level of approval needed for different classes of capital spending.

Comment: Michael: Thanks. It looks like exactly the thing I need. Format itself is fortunatelly completely under my control so I'll head your advice. I'll give it try over the weekend :)

Comment: I've tried the code, but I'm unable to make it run. I understand what you want to achieve, but when i parse it with xalan I get an error - missing $p variable.

I've also reworked the evaluate tag to what I think it should look like, but it still doesn't work. Could you help me to finish it?

Comment: <xsl:evaluate xpath="eq" with-params="map:merge(for $p in data/* return map{name($p):= data/$p})"/>

Comment: The code I gave was for XSLT 3.0, so it definitely won't work with Xalan. It's possible that Xalan has some vendor extension that does something similar, you will have to check. However, Xalan development stopped many years ago, so if you're in the Java world you are much better off using Saxon.

Comment: I've figured that too :). It took me while, because Xalan is not inform you that it doesn't know 3.0 tags. On the other hand, Saxon, at least in the HE version is XSLT 2.0 only too. This "thing" is my private project, which I'm not really willing to invest to much into (as for getting the PE license). Thus I think I'll have to figure out how to rewrite it into 2.0. Thanks for help and pointing me into right direction :).